# Ignore specific characters in regex

Tags: regex

I have this method to check if a string contains a special character, but I don't want it to check for specific characters such as (`+` or `-`) how would I go about doing this?

```
public boolean containsSpecialCharacters(String teamName) {     
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(teamName);

    boolean b = m.find();
    if (b) {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Simply put it in the character class. Just be careful where you place the `-` though. Preferably, you would put it at the end.

Comment: Not related, but just `return b;` instead.

Comment: Simply add those to your negated character class. `[^-+a-z0-9 ]` Also, note that if you place the hyphen as the first character  as shown (or last) then it does not need to be escaped, which greatly simplifies your code when compiling from a string.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
[^\w +-]
```

***REGEX EXPLANATION***

```
[^\w +-]

Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\w +-]»
   A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
   The character “ ” « »
   The character “+” «+»
   The character “-” «-»
```

Comment: `\w` also includes `_`, so you're negating that here also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. Simply add these characters inside of your negated character class.

Within a character class `[]`, you can place a hyphen (`-`) as the first or last character. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to escape it (`\-`) in order to be matched.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)[^a-z0-9 +-]");
```

Regular expression:

```
(?i)            # set flags for this block (case-insensitive) 
[^a-z0-9+-]     # any character except: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9', ' ', '+', '-'
```